# Paypal to open in a new window on click?

Tags: smarty, paypal

I cannot seem to get the code to allow opening a new window instead of staying within the current one. Code:

```
<p class="payment_module">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#paypal_payment_form').submit();" id="paypal_process_payment" title="{l s='Pay with PayPal' mod='paypal'}">
    {if isset($use_mobile) && $use_mobile}
        <img src="{$base_dir_ssl}modules/paypal/img/logos/express_checkout_mobile/CO_{$PayPal_lang_code}_orange_295x43.png" />
    {else}
        {if isset($logos.LocalPayPalHorizontalSolutionPP) && $PayPal_payment_method == $PayPal_integral}
            <img src="{$logos.LocalPayPalHorizontalSolutionPP}" alt="{$PayPal_content.payment_choice}" height="48px" />
        {else}
            <img src="{$logos.LocalPayPalLogoMedium}" alt="{$PayPal_content.payment_choice}" />
        {/if}
        {$PayPal_content.payment_choice}
    {/if}

</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the form you're submitting have target=_blank?

Comment: Hello Preston, No I cant seem to find it anywhere in the files.